# Bounded below Jacobian and global inverse function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function, jacobian, inverse-function-theorem

Recently, I learn about the Hadamard global inverse function theorem. It says that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^2$ and proper (preimage of compact set is again compact) with non-vanishing Jacobian, then $f$ admits a global inverse.

Now, I have a question that given a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|\det(Df)(x)|\geq\delta>0$ and $f(x)$ has bounded derivative up to all orders, whether $f$ is proper or $f$ admits a global inverse?

I have no any idea to construct a counterexample or prove it.  Any opinion is welcome and thanks in advanced.

Comment: Avoid no-idea questions: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Comment: I think the answer is positive and I prove it.